# Why does j = n + 1 in the termination loop invariant of the insertion sort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, insertion-sort, loop-invariant

I am currently reading chapter 2 of the TCRC Introduction to Algorithms 3rd edition textbook and I am reading the author's interpretation of the loop invariant of this algorithm. I understand the author's logic for both the initialization and the maintenance. However, the termination is what I am kind of bogged up on. The author claims that at termination, j = n + 1. However, in the pseudocode of the algorithm, j loops from 2 to n. So shouldn't j = n - 1?

EDIT: The book's pseudo-code for insertion sort is:

```
for j = 2 to A.length
    key = A[j]
    // Insert A[j] into sorted sequence A[1...j - 1]
    i = j - 1
    while i > 0 and A[i] > key
        A[i + 1] = A[i]
        i = i  - 1
    A[i + 1] = key
```

EDIT: After reading it carefully, I have finally understood why j = n + 1 during termination. It's because the for loop goes from 2 to n (inclusively), so after j exceeds n, the loop terminates, hence why j = n + 1 at termination. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you provide the pseudocode?

Comment: You'll have to provide the text of the problem.  There's no way to tell from what you've posted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: I apologize, this is my first time posting on this site, so I am not used to the formatting and conventions that go on here. I provided the pseudocode in the edited OP.

Comment: What is `n` in this context? Is it `A.length`?

Comment: Correct @Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this can be totally incorrect... It is just a brain spit.

Side note: since `j` is incremented during this loop, the starting point is irrelevant for the end condition.

```
 for j = 2 to A.length //A.length = n in your question
```

There is a bit of ambiguity in this pseudo code.

<s>First of all, we assume `j` is defined outside this `for` loop and will have an end value when the loop is terminated.</s> *see @Dukeling's comment*

Second, your code is targeting an array, using the `j` as indexer: `A[j]`

The ambiguity exist with the word `to` in `for j = 2 to A.length`, is it including or excluding `A.length`? and there is this indexer `A[j]`

In common cases, for the indexer in `A[j]`, the valid range for `j` is `[0...A.length -1]`

Some languages uses another range, namely: `[1...A.length]` I think this is intended by the author because `A[0]` is not being hit at all.

If that's the case.... and the `for` condition increments `j` before it breaks the loop (to test the condition and see that it is false), then... you'll get `j = A.length + 1`.

**As a side note:**

In common `C` like languages, arrays have a valid range from `[0...A.length -1]`.

And in this C example, `c` has the value of `A.length` after termination:

```
int c = 0;
for (c = 3; c < A.length; c++)
{

}
//c = A.length after the loop is completed.
```

Comment: We don't really have to assume `j` is defined outside the loop - `j` does increment the final time regardless of where it's defined.

Comment: @Dukeling: You are right on the first part, but as for the second, the focus on 0-indexed, I think that's what caused OP's confusion. Not sure though.

Comment: After reading the pseudocode convention the author uses (same section as the pseudocode in OP), I believe that the author is specifying the index j is at position n + 1, which kind of makes sense considering that the loop ends after the index exceeds the last element of the array.